# SVN update broken on tfs2017

Tags: svn, tfs, build, tfsbuild

Since we upgraded our TFS-Servers from 2015 to 2017, the SVN update command is not working anymore. I installed two TFS to reproduce the issue. On one I installed 2015 and upgraded it to 2017 and another got a fresh 2017 installation. On both machines and with 2017 as well as 2017U1 the problem and the error message is the same. Has anybody a soloution or workaround for this? Currently we have to checkout the whole repository with every build, which consumes a lot of time.
[image: build overview][image: update log]

EDIT: We are using apache SVN server version 1.6.12 with svn:// access.

Tag for SEO: One or more errors occurred. (The startIndex argument must be greater than or equal to zero.)

Comment: How did you use SVN update command in your build definition? Did you just set the clean in repository tab to false?

Comment: exactly, now im using clean sources

Comment: Test on  *TFS2017 update1/SVN 3.6.0* , could not reproduce your issue. Is there some specific settings in your build definition? Did you try to create a new build definition or  a new repo in SVN for test?

Comment: We are using SVN server version 1.6.12 as svn:// access. Have you the opportunity to test it with that config? @Patrick-MSFT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error appearing, but not with every build.

After some trial and error, discovered that this error occurs when there is a directory generated under the $(Build.SourcesDirectory) (i.e. _work\{someNumber}\s) that does not contain an svn workspace. For us it was the TestResults folder created by the VS Test task - [Related issue in vsts-tasks github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/3990)

Adding a step at the end of the build to remove the generated directory fixed it for us.